# Theorem about horizontal composition

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

I want to prove Theorem 1 in section 2.5 of McLane's `Categories for the Working Mathematician`, which was left to the reader.

The theorem:

> The collection of all natural transformations is the set of arrows of
> two different categories under different operations of composition;
> $\circ$ and $*$ (using the notation I'm used to for vertical and
> horizontal respectively) which satisfy the interchange law. Moreover,
> any arrow (natural transformation) which is an identity for $*$ is
> also an identity for $\circ$.

If I am reading this correctly, I need to show that every natural transformation is an arrow in both of these categories.

There is a hint that for the horizontal composition $*$, the category is categories as its objects, while for the vertical composition $\circ$ the category has functors as its objects.

The latter case is simple, since the morphisms in a functor category are natural transformations, and this is a category under vertical composition. For the first category then, I'll take the category whose objects are *all* functors (between all categories). Then every natural transformation is an arrow in this category and every arrow in this category is a natural transformation.

What is the second category? Below is my attempt, but I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

For the former case, I note that any functor $F: A \rightarrow B$ induces a natural transformation $\overline{F}: hom_A \rightarrow hom_B \circ (F \times F)$ by its arrow functions $\overline{F}_{a, b} = F_{a, b} = f \mapsto Ff : hom_A(a, b) \rightarrow hom_B(Fa, Fb)$.

So considering the category of categories as the second category, with arrows (functors) interpreted as natural transformations per above. Composition of functors induces a composition of the induced natural transformations by (for which I'll repurpose $*$, noting this doesn't seem to be the same as horizontal composition) $(\overline{G} * \overline{F})_{a, b} = (\overline{GF})_{a, b} = \overline{G}_{Fa, Fb} \circ \overline{F}_{a, b}$.

I dont think that I have this second category correct, since I think I am supposed to interpret natural transformation as arrows in a category in which composition induces the horizontal composition of natural transformations, but I can't see what that category would be.